# Swig compile the extend files with *.h and *.so without the *.cpp resource code

Tags: c++, gcc, swig

Does SWIG support extending third party modules without having any source code? I just have the *.h and *.so c++ compiled files, but I need to extend the Interface to other languages.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the header files. SWIG only works on function declarations and class/struct/type definitions. Just import the .h you have and SWIG will generate c++ wrapper that calls the C++ code from the target language. You will have to link your application to the SWIG-generated DLL and your .so, or if you are just creating a module, you will link your SWIG-generated DLL to your .so, so when you import/require/use your module from target language, it can resolve SWIG calls to actual C++ functions in your .so.